# Conda update <package>: Permission issues

Tags: xubuntu, python, ipython

I have a frequent issue with python packages, in this case with conda updating packages:

**ipython update**

> user:~$ conda update ipython
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Fetching packages ... Error: Could not open
> u'/home/user/anaconda/pkgs/ipython-2.3.1-py27_0.tar.bz2.part' for
> writing (seek).00  B/s

**ipython notebook update**

> user:~$ pip install "ipython[notebook]"
>
> --upgrade Downloading/unpacking
> ipython[notebook] from
> https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/i/ipython/ipython-2.3.1-py27-none-any.whl#md5=14b9c7c5280ded28777559c434947573
> Downloading ipython-2.3.1-py27-none-any.whl (2.8MB): 2.8MB downloaded
> ...
>
> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.2.1.egg-info'
>
> Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log

**conda update setuptools**

> user:~$ conda update setuptools
>
> Fetching package metadata: .. ...
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Fetching packages ... Error: Could not open
> u'/home/user/anaconda/pkgs/setuptools-7.0-py27_0.tar.bz2.part' for
> writing (seek).0  B/s user:~$Fetching package metadata: .. ...

**Possible Hint:**

This could be related to other issue accessing these packages from python script:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413162/some-python-modules-available-only-with-sudo-others-only-without

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo` before each command? I.e `sudo pip install "ipython[notebook]"`

Comment: $ sudo conda update setuptools ==>  
sudo: conda: command not found $sudo `which conda` update setuptools ==> Error: Could not open u'/home/user/anaconda/pkgs/setuptools-7.0-py27_0.tar.bz2.part' for writing (seek).0  B/s

Comment: hmm, have you tried to reinstall it? It worked directly for me on one machine and on a VM I had to do a link from `~/anaconda/bin/conda` to `/usr/local/bin` to get it to work. You can do a hardlink with `sudo ln ~/anaconda/bin/conda /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Thanks Richard. Indeed the problem was solved by cleaning /tmp from previous failed installations and by uninstalling (pip uninstall) packages mentioned in the permission errors (many packages involved) and reinstalling them (pip install)

Comment: Richard, if you repost your comment as an answer I would mark it as an answered.

Comment: None of the suggestions above worked for me.  The only way I could get around the issue was to move ~/.local/lib/python2.7 to ~/.local/lib/python2.7.old and redo conda update conda etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall it? It worked directly for me on one machine and on a VM I had to do a link from `~/anaconda/bin/conda` to `/usr/local/bin` to get it to work. You can do a hardlink with `sudo ln ~/anaconda/bin/conda /usr/local/bin/`