# sudo permission errors or "command not found" errors when working on a hybrid SSD/HDD setup? (specific example: MATLAB installer)

Tags: partitioning, permissions, sudo, matlab

Since my SSD is small, I still relegate it to only holding the OS.

So, during Ubuntu install, I created a 60 GB partition for `/` on my SSD, and a 500 GB partition for `/home` on my HDD.

However, now I am finding issues such as the one described in this question: [Conda update <package>: Permission issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564298/conda-update-package-permission-issues)

The accepted answer suggested:

`sudo ln ~/anaconda/bin/conda /usr/local/bin/`

I had to use a softlink because I was getting an "invalid cross-device link" error if I did not specify the `-s` for softlink in the command. The following discussion (the very last post) gave me the clue of using a softlink: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/invalid-cross-device-link-731268/

`sudo ln -s ~/anaconda/bin/conda /usr/local/bin/`

Now, I find that I am having an issue that looks superficially similar when using the matlab installer script:

```
brian@brian-linux:~/matlab-installer$ ls
activate.ini  etc      installer_input.txt  license.txt  sys
archives      help     install_guide.pdf    patents.txt  trademarks.txt
bin           install  java                 readme.txt

brian@brian-linux:~/matlab-installer$ ./install
bash: ./install: Permission denied

brian@brian-linux:~/matlab-installer$ sudo ./install
[sudo] password for brian: 
sudo: ./install: command not found

brian@brian-linux:~/matlab-installer$ bash ./install
./install: line 334: /home/brian/matlab-installer/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied

brian@brian-linux:~/matlab-installer$ sudo bash ./install
./install: line 334: /home/brian/matlab-installer/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied
```

What is going on, and how can I prevent such issues once and for all in the future?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ./install`? It _might_ not be executable. (Just in case you didn't check yet; this, however, may only be a part of the problem). Could it be that your `/home` is mounted with the `noexec` parameter? (to check: `mount | grep /home`)

(EDIT: to make it executable you can run `chmod +x ./install`)

Comment: @Kai I think you might be onto the problem. Here's the output of (mount | grep /home): `/dev/sdb2 on /home type ext4 (rw)`. However, I don't see the `noexec` parameter listed in the `fstab` file?

Comment: @Kai Also, initially `ls -l ` gave me the following for `./install`:  -rw------- 1`, so I did run the `chmod` command.

Comment: So it runs with `./install` now? (until you get that "Permission denied" error from line 334 I suppose?) Also, you could have a look at line 334 in the `install` script - if the program tries to run `install_unix` with a path (e.g. simply "/home/brian/matlab-installer/bin/glnxa64/install_unix") then that file _might_ need the executable permission, too. (using the chmod command again).

Comment: @Kai you got that right -- it runs, until line 334. Is it possible these were set to be non-executable because I copied from another hard drive?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (although as far as I know it is rather unusual - however, I could be wrong). How did you copy the files?

Comment: @Kai I copied them to a USB drive using Ctrl+C  and then Ctrl+V (Nautilus). I am having some more permission issues:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/608251/i-cant-run-sudo-on-a-certain-command-because-its-not-in-the-sudo-path-how-c

Comment: If the USB drive was formatted with NTFS or FAT this is the usual thing that happens - those file systems do not store the Linux file permissions as far as I know. It seems that the other permission issues are solved now?

Comment: @Kai Yes, it was a FAT USB, I think...so that might explain it. It seems like other permission issues are solved, for the moment.

Comment: Nice! So you were able to install matlab without further issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because the drive onto which I put `/home` was partitioned as NTFS. This is not good, and among the known issues it causes is permission issues. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/330448/390136) for further detail.